# GridView is not rendered on a page when using Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview, visual-studio-2005

My GridView is not rendered as a table on a page. In fact I do not even see it even though it contains data. I can see it displayed on a page but in "view source" I do not see its htmls.

When I use Visual Studio 2012 to work on the same page, I can see its rendered as a table, but  on 2005 I do not see it.

What can be a problem?

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Portal.master" AutoEventWireup="true" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never"  CodeFile="ISOSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="ISOProcessing_ISOSearch" Title="ISO Search" %>  

    <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>   


   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">    

   </asp:Content>

   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentLeft" Runat="Server">
   </asp:Content>

   <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMain" Runat="Server">

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ISOSearchUpdatePanel" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <div id="divIsoSelect" style="width:700px; height:60px; background-color:white">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">Search ISO by</legend>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlISOSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlISOSearch_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">Select...</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ISO Number" >ISO Number</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Name">Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Region" >Region</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Division">Division</asp:ListItem>                
         </asp:DropDownList></td>
       <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchEntry" runat="server" Visible="false"    style="width:500px; border:gainsboro; border-width: thick;">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="width:120px"><asp:Label ID="lblEntry" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>

                <td valign="top"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                <td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btnFind_Click"/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>               
</fieldset>
 </div>
        <div>    
        <p> <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" style="position:absolute; left: 221px; top: 105px;"></asp:Label></p>
        </div>

            <asp:GridView ID="grvIsoSearchResults" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="15"
                AllowPaging = "true" Visible="true"  BorderColor="Red" GridLines="Both"
                OnRowCommand="grvIsoSearchResults_RowCommand"
                DataKeyNames="isonum" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="grvIsoSearchResults_PageIndexChanging"
                style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">
                <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="100" />
                <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ISONUM" SortExpression="isonum">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvIsoNum" Text = '<%# Eval("ISONUM")%>' runat="server" Width="70px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OFFICE NAME" SortExpression="isoofficename">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvIsoOfficeName" Text = '<%# Eval("ISOOFFICENAME")%>' runat="server" Width="200px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REGION" SortExpression="region">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvRegion" Text = '<%# Eval("REGION")%>' runat="server" Width="50px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DIVISION" SortExpression="client_id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvDivision" Text = '<%# Eval("CLIENT_ID")%>' runat="server" Width="50px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMAIL ADDRESS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvEmailAddress" Text = '<%# Eval("EMAIL")%>' runat="server" Width="200px" />                                                                  
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEmailUpdate" Text = "Update" CommandName="UpdateEmail" runat="server" onClientClick="ValidateEmail()"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <pagerstyle backcolor="#005482" ForeColor="White" height="30px" verticalalign="Bottom" horizontalalign="Center"/>
            </asp:GridView> 
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="false" ShowSummary="true"/>

  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
        Please Wait.....
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you see it if you take it out of the UpdatePanel?

Comment: When doing that, Grid will not show after clicking "find"

Comment: Is there is any particular way to put a grid on a page, like inside of `<div>` tags or something like that.

Comment: And also, a lot of controls are highlighted eith red in a code with the following error message "Element ....is not known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web Site"